Tangent Criterion In Euclidean Geometry
Source:"Euclidean Geometry In Mathematical Olympiads" By Evan Chen

I am having a lot of trouble proving that $(i)\iff (iii)$. The book considers this as a limiting case of a cyclic quadrilateral but I am not entirely convinced. Moreover, I also found Bidirectionally of the "Tangent Criterion" where the page deals with the exact problem. However, I also can't seem to make anything out of the hints given.
My work:

Moving point $C$ in the major arc $AB$ while $\angle ACB$ remains constant and also considering $AB$ as diameter (as mentioned in the page).
I should also mention that the notation in the book refer to directed angles but that shouldn't be a problem. I am sorry if the solution is too obvious and thank you for reading my problem.

May I give a proof to (ii) <---> (iii) instead?

Doug Ngo yes of course, proving (i)<-->(ii) is quite trivial.

Instead of proving that (ii) $\Longleftrightarrow$ (iii), I will show that (i) $\Longleftrightarrow$ (iii), as (i) $\Longleftrightarrow$ (ii) follows directly from the definition of a tangent line.
Let $AD$ be the diameter of $(ABC)$.
If $B\equiv D$ then $\measuredangle BAD = 0 = \frac{\pi}{2} - \measuredangle ACB$.
If $B\not\equiv D$ then $\measuredangle BAD = \pi - \measuredangle ADB - \measuredangle DBA = \pi - \measuredangle ACB - \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \measuredangle ACB$.
\begin{align*}
  \text{$AP$ is tangent to $(ABC)$} & \Longleftrightarrow AP \perp AD \\
                                    & \Longleftrightarrow \measuredangle PAB + \measuredangle BAD = \frac{\pi}{2} \\
                                    & \Longleftrightarrow \measuredangle PAB = \frac{\pi}{2} - \measuredangle BAD \\
                                    & \Longleftrightarrow \measuredangle PAB = \measuredangle ACB
\end{align*}
Hence (i) $\Longleftrightarrow$ (iii).
Comment: I agree that considering (iii) as a limiting case is not rigorous but that is a useful intuition.

Thanks a lot! This was quite an oversight by me as the proof seems very natural.

Here's an alternative using the inscribed angle theorem, which you'll probably have come across. It's a circle theorem illustrated in the below diagram:

IAT (for short) states that the angle subtended by an arc at the center is twice the angle subtended at the circumference. A simple proof for this theorem can be constructed by joining $OA$ to make use of isosceles triangles.
Back to your question, to prove (iii), which is often dubbed as the alternate segment theorem, we will also make use of (ii).
In your diagram, join $OA, OB, OC$. Let $\angle PAB = \theta$, then it follows from (ii) that:
$$\angle BAO = 90 - \theta$$
Also, $\angle CAO = \angle ACO = \angle A - 90 + \theta$, where $\angle A = \angle BAC$.
By IAT, $\angle BOC = 2\angle A$, so $\angle BCO = 90 - \angle A$. Now, we clearly see that:
$$\boxed{\therefore\angle ACB = \angle BCO + \angle ACO = \theta = \angle PAB}$$
So, I guess that was the utilization of (i) & (ii) to prove the alternate segment theorem. And of course, this working can be taken in the opposite direction as well!
